# Azure DevOps Promote NuGet packages to Release view

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

As part of an Azure DevOps pipeline, I would like to promote packages in our own NuGet feed to 'Release' view as part of the release build.

I have an application that traverses all project.assets.json files and find names and versions of packages used by the projects in the solution.
This list is reduced by pattern matching on names to our own packages.

Previously I have succesfully used the BuildHttpClient from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi to access information about builds and build artifacts.

What are the available tools for accessing Nuget Packages, feeds and views?

The REST API is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update%20package%20versions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0, but I would hate to implement the classes myself, if there is a library for the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nuget - Update Package Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update%20package%20versions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) has a flaw - there is no {project} relevans for packages.

By adding [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.Client Version 16.179.0-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.Client/16.179.0-preview) we get the classes, we need as long as we are building .Net Framework 4.6.2 or later (no netstandard yet).

based on this, I built the following helper class (no exception handling or threading to keep it simple):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.NuGet.WebApi.Types;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Packaging.Shared.WebApi;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PromotePackages
{
    public class PromotePackageBatch
    {
        private readonly string _organization;
        private readonly string _feedId;
        private readonly string _token;

        public PromotePackageBatch(string organization, string feedId, string token)
        {
            _organization = organization;
            _feedId = feedId;
            _token = token;
        }

        public void PromotePackagesToView(IDictionary<string, string> Libraries, string viewName)
        {
            var packs = new List<MinimalPackageDetails>();
            foreach (var kvp in Libraries)
            {
                packs.Add(new MinimalPackageDetails
                {
                    Id = kvp.Key,
                    Version = kvp.Value
                });
            }
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                NuGetPackagesBatchRequest req = new NuGetPackagesBatchRequest
                {
                    Data = new BatchPromoteData
                    {
                        ViewId = viewName
                    },
                    Operation = 0,
                    Packages = packs
                };

                var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", _token))));

                var response = client.PostAsync(BuildUri(), httpContent).Result;

                var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }

        private Uri BuildUri()
        {
            return new Uri($"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{_organization}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{_feedId}/nuget/packagesbatch?api-version=6.0-preview.1");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @EdwardHan-MSFT Thanks for your help. I will accept it as soon as I can (24hrs limit)

Answer (score 0):

By reference to this doc: [Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK API Reference](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2F%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-dotnet&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C5d4171e7fd344b1b7e3308d8b7860ee4%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637461133688658283%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=nXgqrNksN%2BxQiuJr%2BsEXnl6JxY%2Bj0tdTOFS05LuZ0Qo%3D&reserved=0), searching for any managed APIs by typing in the box, but we don’t find such library which implements this Rest API: [NuGet - Update Package Versions](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifactspackagetypes%2Fnuget%2Fupdate%2520package%2520versions%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-rest-6.0&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C5d4171e7fd344b1b7e3308d8b7860ee4%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637461133688668279%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=4LbvwS8ZiK2gcGncTRRe4NhFElN%2B1KCUgqrWYeKu05Y%3D&reserved=0).

You could create a new issue in the [MicrosoftDocs/feedback repository on GitHub](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoftDocs%2Ffeedback%2Fissues&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C5d4171e7fd344b1b7e3308d8b7860ee4%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637461133688678275%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=7fhSYJx3NmtD2%2FDm9yzi%2BDOXIGe2COhviqWmv%2B0NwFE%3D&reserved=0) for this feedback.

And now we suggest that you directly use this Rest API to implement this.

Comment: I have added an issue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/3380